# Pattern svg shows on page but pattern does not

Tags: svg

I have an svg pattern here

It outputs the svg but does not display the pattern

It should be straight diagonal lines.

Is there a reason the pattern is not displaying.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="400px" width="400px">
    <defs>
        <pattern
            id="diagonalHatch"
            width="3"
            height="3"
            patternTransform="rotate(45 0 0)"
            patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <line x1="4" x2="4" y1="0" y2="10" style="stroke:red; stroke-width:5" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: What are you applying the pattern to?

Comment: I'm trying to add it as a background to a simple div. Its not working and thought it might be the svg that was broke. I thought I should at least be able to see the pattern on a page

Comment: You need to add a path where the fill is the pattern, for example: `<rect width="400" height="400" fill="url(#diagonalHatch)"></rect>`

Comment: patterns apply to SVG elements, not to html elements such as <div>

Comment: thanks, I'll ask a better question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use it as a background in css you need to transform the SVG to a data-uri image. Also in css a background image repeats in a pattern unless you set `background-repeat:none`. What you really need is a small SVG that repeats itself into a pattern

```css
.bg {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='20' height='20'%3E%3Cpath stroke='red' stroke-width='1' id='squares' d='M5 0 L0 5 m0 5 L10 0 m 5 0 L0 15 m0 5 L20 0 m0 5 L5 20 m5 0 L20 10 m0 5 L15 20' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  border: 1px;
}

svg{border:1px solid
```

```html
<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='20' height='20' ><path  stroke='red' stroke-width='1' id='squares' d='M5 0 L0 5 m0 5 L10 0 m 5 0 L0 15 m0 5 L20 0 m0 5 L5 20 m5 0 L20 10 m0 5 L15 20' /></svg>


<div class="bg"></div>
```

In order to get the data-uri you need I recommend https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs

FDor an explanation of how to do it you may read [Optimizing SVGs in data URIs](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris)